# How do I type a decorated property which type is changed by the decorator?

Tags: typescript, ember.js, decorator, typescript-decorator, ember-concurrency

Here's some code that works perfectly in JS:

```typescript
import Component from '@ember/component';
import {task} from 'ember-concurrency';

class Foo extends Component {
  currentRecordId!: string; // passed from template

  @task
  fetchRecord *(id) {
    return yield this.store.findRecord('foo', id);
  }

  async fetchCurrentRecord() {
    return this.fetchRecord.perform(this.currentRecordId);
  }
}
```

Ember Concurrency is an alternative to promises that allows cancelling and managing them similar to Observable from RxJS. Since JS promises don't allow cancelling, Ember Concurrency uses `yield` instead of `async`/`await`.

The `task` decorator used above converts a generator function into a `TaskProperty` instance that has a `.perform()` method.

Please note, that, though weird, this pattern has proven its handiness and reliability in non-typed JS apps.

But typing it presents a challenge.

---

Here are

```typescript
export declare function task<T, A>(generatorFn: () => Iterator<T>): Task<T, () => TaskInstance<T>>;

export declare function task<T, A>(
  generatorFn: (a: A) => Iterator<T>
): Task<T, (a: A) => TaskInstance<T>>;

export declare function task<T, A>(
  generatorFn: (a: A) => Iterator<PromiseLike<T>>
): Task<T, (a: A) => TaskInstance<T>>;

export declare function task<T, A1, A2>(
  generatorFn: (a1: A1, a2: A2) => Iterator<T>
): Task<T, (a1: A1, a2: A2) => TaskInstance<T>>;

// More variants of arguments skipped

export interface TaskInstance<T> extends PromiseLike<T> {
  readonly error?: any;
  readonly hasStarted: ComputedProperty<boolean>;
  readonly isCanceled: ComputedProperty<boolean>;
  readonly isDropped: ComputedProperty<boolean>;
  readonly isError: boolean;
  readonly isFinished: ComputedProperty<boolean>;
  readonly isRunning: ComputedProperty<boolean>;
  readonly isSuccessful: boolean;
  readonly state: ComputedProperty<TaskInstanceState>;
  readonly value?: T;
  cancel(): void;
  catch(): RSVP.Promise<any>;
  finally(): RSVP.Promise<any>;
  then<TResult1 = T, TResult2 = never>(
    onfulfilled?: ((value: T) => TResult1 | RSVP.Promise<TResult1>) | undefined | null,
    onrejected?: ((reason: any) => TResult2 | PromiseLike<TResult2>) | undefined | null
  ): RSVP.Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>;
}

interface Task<T> extends TaskProperty<T> {
    readonly isIdle: boolean;
    readonly isQueued: boolean;
    readonly isRunning: boolean;
    readonly last?: TaskInstance<T>;
    readonly lastCanceled?: TaskInstance<T>;
    readonly lastComplete?: TaskInstance<T>;
    readonly lastErrored?: TaskInstance<T>;
    readonly lastIncomplete?: TaskInstance<T>;
    readonly lastPerformed?: TaskInstance<T>;
    readonly lastRunning?: TaskInstance<T>;
    readonly lastSuccessful?: TaskInstance<T>;
    readonly performCount: number;
    readonly state: TaskState;
    perform(...args: any[]): TaskInstance<T>;
    cancelAll(): void;
}

export interface TaskProperty<T> extends ComputedProperty<T> {
    cancelOn(eventNames: string[]): this;
    debug(): this;
    drop(): this;
    enqueue(): this;
    group(groupPath: string): this;
    keepLatest(): this;
    maxConcurrency(n: number): this;
    on(eventNames: string[]): this;
    restartable(): this;
}
```

These types aren't official and can be customized.

---

I struggle with properly typing the topmost code sample.

The error I'm getting is:

> Property `perform` does not exist on type `() => IterableIterator<any>`.

It is understandable, since `fetchRecord` is defined as a generator.

Moreover, TypeScript [officially does not support](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4881) decorators that change the type of decorated property.

So the question is: **how to work around the limitation and type such a decorator without reverting to `@ts-ignore`?**

In addition to typing the `fetchRecord` property, I would like to properly type the arguments that I pass into `this.fetchRecord.perform()` and which are received by the generator.

Thank you. ^__^

Comment: [Please don't put tags in question titles "You should not force a tag into your title."](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Shouldn't the return `generatorFn` return an iteration of promises ?